# How to exclude current user from all users using email?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I want to select all users except current longlined user using email address, I don't want to show his details so how it is possible in node js?

```
    router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
      const jsonObj = jsonToken.verify(req.cookies.email, process.env.privateKey);
      const userEmail = jsonObj.userEmail
      console.log(userEmail)
      userModel.find().exec((err, data)=> {
        if (err) throw err;
        res.status(200).json(data);
        res.render('index', { title: 'Secret Santa', users: data });
      })
```

Comment: just try `userModel.find({ email { $ne: userEmail } }).`

Comment: yes working userModel.find({ email : { $ne: userEmail } }) with this code thanks Buddy

Comment: If it does in fact answer the question you asked then please note to [Accept your Answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) to the questions you ask

Answer (score 0):

You can add not equal to condition in your find query,

```
userModel.find({ email: { $ne: userEmail } }).exec((err, data)=> {
  if (err) throw err;
  res.status(200).json(data);
  res.render('index', { title: 'Secret Santa', users: data });
})
```